# Layout inspector shows no recomposition, although composable renders list in different order

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple composable like this which renders a list of `Int`s and has a button that changes the list to another list with the order reversed:

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    var list by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf(1, 2, 3)) }

    Column {
        list.forEach {
            key(it) {
                Text(text = it.toString())
            }
        }
        Button(onClick = {
            list = list.reversed()
        }) {
            Text(text = "reverse list")
        }
    }
}
```

When running this and checking the layout inspector I see that, since I'm using the `key` composable, each `Text` skips recomposition as shown below (as expected):

[image]

But the compostables renders the list in reverse order. I'm curious to know why the layout inspector does not show any recomposition occurred although the list gets rendered in a different order. Something must be recomposing behind scenes (choosing where to place rendering of the text compostables). Is the layout inspector hiding some recompositions? Or the placement of the compostables does not count as a recomposition?

[image]

Comment: What you see in your layout inspector is not correct. When i run the Layout Inspector `Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Beta 6` i see only one that skips recomposition is the one in the middle as expected since it's always `2`.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I copied and pasted a different composable that is not using `key` composable. I'll update now

Answer (score 1):

Items are placed during the Layout phase, which is separate from the Composition phase. [Official guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/phases) on Jetpack Compose phases.

Edit: [Here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#defer-reads) are few examples that involve phase skipping.